# how to display popup window from windows service running a powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-services

i wrote a posh script running in a windows service.  From specific action on the computer, I need to display a popup window warning the user.

```
$popupMsg = @" message "@   
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($user+ $popupMsg,"Remote Connection Information","OK","Warning")
```

When I run this script from PowerGui, the popup displays fine, but when i run the windows service that runs this script, the popup won't show up.
What's wrong in this ?  Thanks people !

Comment: Services are by definition non-interactive. To display a dialog from one, you would have to invoke a foreground script, with the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting "Allow service to interact with desktop" in the Service settings:

[image]

Comment: I cannot do that as I'm using the 'This account' option to specify an applicative logon wich is allowed to run the service

Answer (score 1):

What version of Windows do you wish to support? [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation) will prevent you from showing any kind of GUI on a user's desktop on Vista and beyond.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using essentially Win 7 and just a little bit of win xp... So I guess there's no solution for me then...  What about asking my service to launch a .exe file when timer tick ?  Would that do the trick ?

Comment: [Launching an exe in the user's session](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36581/Interaction-between-services-and-applications-at-u) is an option but may be overkill. If you can figure out the ID of the user's session, you can use [WTSSendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display a message box there.